# Moving cells to new sections in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

How would I move cells from my first section in my tableview to the second section after the users selects the button?

This establishes my tableview.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var goalTableView: UITableView!

    let sections: [String] = ["Today:", "History:"]
    var goals: [[String]] = [["Goal 1", "Goal 2", "Goal 3"], [""]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

In my viewdidload I would add a connection from my button to my view controller, but would I have to develop a function here to move the selected cell to the new section?

```
        let headerView = UIView()
        goalTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:   view.frame.width, height: 5)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return goals[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
        cell?.goalLabel.text = goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell?.cellDelegate = self
        cell?.index = indexPath
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return goals.count
    }
}

extension ViewController: GoalTableView {
    func selectGoalButton(index: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are selecting a cell to move, then why not use didSelectRowAt ?  I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with a separate button ?

Comment: Once the user clicks on a button within the cell, I want that cell to automatically go to the second section, because the button is also already connected to a progress bar. So the user only has to make one selection. If I use the didSelectRowAt will that impact how many times the user has to select the cell?

Comment: Unless you have some other UI event going on in your cell, I cannot see why you can't use didSelectRowAt.  I'll post a solution for you shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Only move cell from the 1st section
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        // Append the selected element to the second array
        goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])

        // Remove the selected element from the first array
        goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```